# Consider the two regions bounded by the curves $ \ y=\frac{x+1}{2} \ $ and $ \ x=y^3-y^2-4y-1 \ $

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the two regions bounded by the curves $ \ y=\frac{x+1}{2} \ $ and $ \ x=y^3-y^2-4y-1 \ $

[image]

Find the Centroid of the region **above x-axis** .

Find the Centroid of the region **below** **x-axis** .

**Answer:**

The  curves $ \ y=\frac{x+1}{2} \ $ and $ \ x=y^3-y^2-4y-1 \ $ intersects at $ \ (-1,0), \ (5,3) , \ (-5,-2) \ $

Now,

$ y=\frac{x+1}{2} \ \Rightarrow x=2y-1=f(y) \ , say $

Also let $ \ g(y)=x=y^3-y^2-4y-1 \ $

The area $ \ A_1 \ $ above x-axis is given by

$ A_1=\int_{0}^{3} (f(y)-g(y)) dy \\ \Rightarrow  A_1=\int_{0}^{3} (-y^3+y^2+6y) dy \\ \Rightarrow A_1=15.75 \ $

Let $ \ (\bar x, \bar y) \ $ be the centroid of the region above x-axis .

Then ,

$ \bar x=\frac{1}{A_1} \int_0^3 y(g(y)-f(y)) dy=1.629 \ $

But I am not sure about the work.

Can some help me finding the above centroid.

Comment: what about the other coordinate $ \ \bar y \ $

Answer (score 2):

You found the area of the region above $x$-axis correctly:
$$A_1=\int_{0}^{3} (f(y)-g(y)) dy=15.75.$$
The centroid of the region above $x$-axis:
$$\bar{y}=\frac{1}{A_1}\int_0^3y\left[f(y)-g(y)\right]dy=1.629; \\
\bar{x}=\frac{1}{A_1}\int_0^3 \frac12\left[f^2(y)-g^2(y)\right]dy=-0.976.$$